# MSDistributeDelegate distribute method not called

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane

This is my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import AppCenter
import AppCenterDistribute
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MSDistributeDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        MSDistribute.setDelegate(self)
        MSAppCenter.start("...", withServices: [MSDistribute.self])

        return true
    }

    func distribute(_ distribute: MSDistribute!, releaseAvailableWith details: MSReleaseDetails!) -> Bool {

         // Your code to present your UI to the user, e.g. an UIAlertController.
         let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Update available.",
                                               message: "Do you want to update?",
                                        preferredStyle:.alert)

         alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Update", style: .cancel) {_ in
           MSDistribute.notify(.update)
         })

         alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Postpone", style: .default) {_ in
           MSDistribute.notify(.postpone)
         })

         // Show the alert controller.
         self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true)
         return true;
       }

}
```

So when I make say build 1, with this code, and then publish a new build to Contributors (or internal or public group of testers), and when they try to open their current app (build 1), this code doesn't run.

I have followed App Center examples for this and among other things I added this to my info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>"appcenter-..."</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
```

But nothing happens. Am I not understanding this how it should work? I thought that a browser should open a link that takes us to the update page, and then we return back to the updated app.

Am I missing something? How to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I added my working code, just compare with it.
If your delegate method is not calling then there might be a few reason:

1. Check your framework version (Sometime framework has some issues)
2. Check your appcenter secret key bcz that key should be in proper format e.g. appcenter-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX (Copy key from appcenter website and paste as it in your code)

   @available(iOS 11.0, *)
   extension AppDelegate: MSDistributeDelegate {

   ```
   private func initializeAppCenterSDK() {
       #if DEBUG
       MSAppCenter.start(appCenterSecretKey, withServices:[MSCrashes.self])
       #else
       MSDistribute.updateTrack = .private
       MSDistribute.setDelegate(self)
       MSAppCenter.start(appCenterSecretKey, withServices:[MSCrashes.self, MSDistribute.self])
       #endif
   }

   func distribute(_ distribute: MSDistribute!, releaseAvailableWith details: MSReleaseDetails!) -> Bool {
       //TODO: Need to localized
       Logger.info(" \(#function) Distribute method called ankit ", category: .chatFlow)
       let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Update available for UCC.", message: "Do you want to update?", preferredStyle:.alert)
       alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Update", style: .cancel) {_ in
           MSDistribute.notify(.update)
       })
       alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Postpone", style: .default) {_ in
           MSDistribute.notify(.postpone)
       })

       self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true)
       return true;
   }
   ```

   }

[image: app update popup]